# Create a custom filter outside of a table in Tanstack-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a table created with Tanstack-table and I want to create a search bar to search in the table (only in one column). The problem is that all the examples show the search bar inside the header of the table or use react-table v7.
Here's my useReactTable hook :

```
const table = useReactTable({
  data: data ?? [],
  columns,
  enableColumnFilters: true,
  enableFilters: true,
  state: {
    sorting,
  },
  onSortingChange: setSorting,
  getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
  getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
  debugTable: true,
});
```

Here's the column that I want to filter with :

```
{
  accessorKey: `name`,
  id: `sort`,
  header: `Name`,
  cell: (info) => (
    <TBold>
      <TLink
        href={{
          pathname: `/move/[name]`,
          query: { name: info.getValue<string>() },
        }}
      >
        {removeDash(info.getValue<string>())}
      </TLink>
    </TBold>
  )
}
```

And here's what renders my table :

```
<section>
  <LeftTitle>Moves</LeftTitle>
  <input
    type="text"

  />
  <TableContainer ref={tableContainerRef}>
    <FullWidthTable>
      {tableHeader()}
      {tableBody()}
    </FullWidthTable>
  </TableContainer>
</section>
```

Idk what method brought by tanstack-table I should use or if a 'normal' (with a useState and an onChange) could work because Idk how to access the value inside the column.
What should I do to make a working filter with the methods brought by tanstack-table ?